# How do I create a dockerfile and docker-compose.yml from the commands?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, docker-compose, dockerfile, tensorflow-serving

I have a problem. I have the following commands.

```
docker pull tensorflow/serving

docker run -it -v \folder\model:/model-p 8601:8601 --entrypoint /bin/bash tensorflow/serving

tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8601 --model_name=model --model_base_path=/model/
```

I would like to add these to a `dockerfile` and to a `docker-compose`.yml. The problem is that the `models` are under the following folder structure. So I would have to go back one folder and into another. How exactly do I make it all work?

folder structure

```
folder
├── model # should be copied to \model
│     └── 1
│         └── ...
│     └── 2
│         └── ...
├── server
│     └── Dockerfile
│     └── docker-compose.yml
```

```
FROM tensorflow/serving
```

```yaml
services:
  tfserving:
    container_name: tfserving
    image: tensorflow/serving
    ports:
      - "8601:8601"
    volumes:
      - \folder\model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dockerfile (name it with capital D so it's recognized by docker-compose with just . (dot) since it's in the same folder):

```
FROM tensorflow/serving
EXPOSE 8601
RUN tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8601 --model_name=model --model_base_path=/model/
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  tfserving:
    container_name: tfserving
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8601:8601"
    volumes:
      - ../model:/models/model
    environment:
      - TENSORFLOW_SERVING_MODEL_NAME=model
    entrypoint: [ "bash", "-c", "tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8601 --model_name=model --model_base_path=/models/model/"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, the other parameters are still missing, how do I incorporate them?

Comment: I updated my answer. @Test you mean the entrypoint?

Comment: thank you very much. I mean `tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8601 --model_name=model --model_base_path=/model/`

Comment: I also got an error `=> ERROR [3/3] COPY ../models ./models` :/

Comment: @Test My bad since I didn`t know how tensorflow image works. See update and try.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. But I got inside the logs the following error `Could not find base path /models/model for servable model with error Not found: /models/model not found`. He created inside a folder `models` but not the `model` with the actual models.

Comment: @Test I've been looking in [DockerHub Tensorflow](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/tensorflow-serving) and I'm not sure if models are stored in the volume I put in the docker-compose. See if `../model:/models/model` works

Comment: That worked! The Container started successfully. But in the container I need to run the following command `tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8601 --model_name=model --model_base_path=/models/model/`. Is there an option to do this inside the `docker-compse.yml`? So that I do not run this command manually?

Comment: @Test ... `--model_name=model ` and `--model_base_path=/models/model/` are already defined in the docker-compose. Try adding in environment `TENSORFLOW_SERVING_REST_API_PORT_NUMBER=8061` for the `--rest_api_port` param. Then just run with `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Thank you! I added that, but the funny thing is it doesn't work. However, as soon as I write the command into Docker and execute it, everything works.

Comment: @Test See the Dockerfile update. Maybe that works.